# why are there many in-progress files after restarting flink program?

Tags: hdfs, apache-flink

I use flink to consume kafka and save them to hdfs in parquet format. Now I find that so many inprogress files in my target directory , which will not close as a file in target dir when I restart my flink program.

My envs:

```
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)
    env.enableCheckpointing(60000)
    env.getCheckpointConfig.setCheckpointingMode(CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE)
    env.getConfig.registerTypeWithKryoSerializer(classOf[MyMessage],classOf[ProtobufSerializer])


//sinks

    val bucketAssigner = new DateTimeBucketAssigner[myCounter]("yyyy-MM-dd", ZoneId.of("Asia/Shanghai"))
    val streamingFileSink = StreamingFileSink.
      forBulkFormat(path, ParquetAvroWriters.forSpecificRecord(classOf[myCounter]))
      .withBucketCheckInterval(60000)
      .withBucketAssigner(bucketAssigner).build
```

```
-rw-r--r--   3 Administrator hdfs       1629 2019-08-05 17:06 /user/data/2019-08-05/.part-2-0.inprogress.722265d7-1082-4c84-b70d-da2a08092f5d
-rw-r--r--   3 Administrator hdfs       1891 2019-08-05 17:07 /user/data/2019-08-05/.part-2-1.inprogress.ac0d8b56-b8f0-4893-9e55-5374b69f16cc
-rw-r--r--   3 Administrator hdfs       1891 2019-08-05 17:08 /user/data/2019-08-05/.part-2-2.inprogress.a427c2e2-d689-42b8-aa3d-77873c5654f2
-rw-r--r--   3 Administrator hdfs       1891 2019-08-05 17:09 /user/data/2019-08-05/.part-2-3.inprogress.b5c746e3-354d-4ab3-b1a4-8c6bd88ae430
-rw-r--r--   3 Administrator hdfs       1891 2019-08-05 16:59 /user/data/2019-08-05/.part-2-3.inprogress.e286d995-3fa7-4696-b51a-27378412a35c
-rw-r--r--   3 Administrator hdfs       1891 2019-08-05 17:00 /user/data/2019-08-05/.part-2-4.inprogress.bcde4f30-2f78-4f54-92ad-9bc54ac57c5c
-rw-r--r--   3 Administrator hdfs       1891 2019-08-05 17:10 /user/data/2019-08-05/.part-2-4.inprogress.dbce8a00-6514-43dc-8b31-36c5a8665d37
-rw-r--r--   3 Administrator hdfs          0 2019-08-05 17:10 /user/data/2019-08-05/.part-2-5.inprogress.34e53418-f5af-4279-87ef-6a27549d90fe
-rw-r--r--   3 Administrator hdfs       1891 2019-08-05 17:01 /user/data/2019-08-05/.part-2-5.inprogress.936cdb63-4fe2-41bf-b839-2861030c5516
-rw-r--r--   3 Administrator hdfs          0 2019-08-05 16:55 /user/data/2019-08-05/.part-2-6.inprogress.7a7099a6-9dcd-450b-af2c-8a676276ef0a
-rw-r--r--   3 Administrator hdfs          0 2019-08-05 17:01 /user/data/2019-08-05/.part-2-6.inprogress.b57f548f-45fc-497c-9807-ef18dba3d11d
-rw-r--r--   3 Administrator hdfs       1574 2019-08-05 16:56 /user/data/2019-08-05/part-2-0
-rw-r--r--   3 Administrator hdfs       1868 2019-08-05 16:57 /user/data/2019-08-05/part-2-1
-rw-r--r--   3 Administrator hdfs       1891 2019-08-05 16:58 /user/data/2019-08-05/part-2-2
-rw-r--r--   3 Administrator hdfs       1661 2019-08-05 16:53 /user/data/2019-08-05/part-2-3
-rw-r--r--   3 Administrator hdfs       1891 2019-08-05 16:54 /user/data/2019-08-05/part-2-4
```

I think the reason is that the in-progress file is not close when I restart the program, I'm confused that why the files will not close after restart, even the new files are became in-progress. Could someone explalin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For short, for Exactly-Once semantic.

Pls read [this post](https://flink.apache.org/features/2018/03/01/end-to-end-exactly-once-apache-flink.html) from Flink offical blog first.

Then let me make some attempts to explain it clearly.

1. BucketingSink write all records to temp file, by default with suffix in-progress.
2. When the time to checkpointing on this sink comes, Flink will save the name fo the in-progress files to the checkpoint;
3. When It's time for commit, Flink will rename in-progress files to final names, on your examples, they are part-x-x files.

And when you restart Flink application, Flink job will restart from last savepoint(If you set the parameters), and many in-progress files which were not ready for commit, will be abandoned, and never be read(starts with dot will not be list by HDFS) by the users.

Of course, I ignored many details, for examples, a file will be rename to .pending files when it's volume exceed the configuration, ect.

Comment: in my case, I didn't set the checkpoint path in this way 
env.setStateBackend(new FsStateBackend("hdfs:///user//data/flink/checkpoints")).
Does flink clean the checkpoint after the cancel lead to in-progress never close?

Comment: besides, I notice that the counters start from 0 after restarting. Does it also caused by the lack of checkpoint? Will it resume from in-progress if I set the checkpoint?

Comment: According to the source code of BucketingSink, Flink never delete the .in-progress files even when you start from checkpoint.

Comment: Flink HA will auto restart job according to your restart strategy  when error happens. If you just cancel the job from the UI，there is no checkpoint left.

Use -s parameter to cancel Flink job, you will get the savepoint, then start from savepoint.

Comment: Will it resume to write the in-progress files and turn them to finish state if get the savepoint?

Comment: Yes, it will be renamed to final part-x-x name.

Comment: will it reset the counter? in my case, it seems to reset the counter without checkpoint

Comment: Counter will be reseted every time you start the job. The counter is transient, not be serialized in savepoint or checkpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit your application with flink shell to make the application restoring from savepoint, like this:
`./bin/flink run -s <savepointPath> ...`, check [this](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/cli.html#restore-a-savepoint) for more details.
`StreamingFileSink` will handle inprogress files.

Comment: That's what I do. I run the flink on windows + IDEA to consume the data on linux server for test. I restrart my app by rerun on IDEA

Comment: So you `flink stop` your application and run it from IDEA again, right? I think it should rename *inprogress* files if stopped correctly.

Comment: No. I didn't ``flink stop``, I just rerun my flink program on IDEA.

Comment: It seems you need to submit your application with flink shell, since you cannot restore an application from code (so you cannot restore an application started with IDEA).

Comment: got it. I'll give it a try. Thanks!